# How do I embed a live Instagram feed to a webpage rather than individual posts?

Tags: html, instagram

I am aware that I can embed individual Instagram posts to my website in HTML, but I want to embed a live feed consisting of the five most recent posts which update along with the profile in real-time.

For those who want to know why: I want this feature to be part of the "Photoblog" page of my site without having to have visitors navigate away.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use their API.

You have this endpoint: `https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/media/` where you don't need any token.
It gives you the last 20 posts.

Then you just display that on your site :)

Comment: I see. I am somewhat new to this, so would you mind telling me how would I implement that into my code? Some example code would be great. Thank you.